# filter with url: should be very easy but doesn't seem to work?

Tags: list, filter, url, parameter

This is really weird as it seems so simple to me, but just won't work.

```
 myserver/site/lists/ExampleList/AllItems.aspx?ID=133
```

isn't this the basic url filter to only show that item?

it does work however if I use

```
 ?FilterName=ID&FilterMultiValue=133
```

but this just seems wrong to me as I am only filtering by the id (ya know...to send emails with link to the item/doc). am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are thinking of the new/edit/display forms which usually look like this:

```
dispform.aspx?ID=133
```

Comment: right. this is totally correct...not sure what I was thinking. thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

AllItems.aspx is a view and as such it expects to display multiple items which is why the second approach works.  That syntax creates a filter on the view based on the ID field and shows the ID you specify.  This is the same thing that happens when you filter on a column from a view.

If you are looking to link directly to an item, the URL would be something like this :

`myserver/site/lists/ExampleList/DispForm.aspx?ID=133`